# How to use not custom Exception Constructor?

Tags: java

In Javadoc, I can see Class ClassCastException's Constructor with String parameter. But ClassCastException's Instance automatically is created (by JVM), I don't know how to use ClassCastException's Constructor.

In my code, I want to get a result "wrong", not "B cannot be cast to C".

```java
class Prac {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ClassCastException e = new ClassCastException("wrong");
            A a = new B();
            C c = (C)a;
        }
        catch(ClassCastException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

    }
}

class A {

}

class B extends A {

}

class C extends A{

}
```

Result : B cannot be cast to C

Comment: Catch it and throw your own.

Comment: You can use `throw new ClassCastException("wrong");`

Comment: Why would you want a runtime exception to have less / incorrect information?

Answer (score 0):

If you want the result "wrong", then just print "wrong".

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        A a = new B();
        C c = (C)a;
    }
    catch(ClassCastException e) {
        System.out.println("wrong");
    }
}
```

No need to go tinkering around with the exception.